# Variable addressing

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

```
int main()
{

    int a = 10;

    int *p;   // int *p = a; gives me an error: invalid conversion from int to int *.
              // Tell me why?

    *p = a;   // while this runs

    cout << &a <<"  "<<p;
}
```

Secondly &a and p gives 2 different values. According to me Address of a and the value stored in pointer p should be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *p = a`, interpreted literally, takes the *value* stored in `a` and tries to interpret it as a *memory address* to store in `p`. While computationally legal, C++ won't allow this without an explicit typecast, because this is normally *not* what you want to do.

The reason why the statement `int *p = a` is different from `*p = a` is simple: the first statement, shorthand for the following

```
int *p;
p = a;
```

is *initializing* the pointer, so it expects a memory address on the RHS, while the second statement is assigning a value to the location pointed to by `p`, so expects (in this case) an integer on the RHS.

If you want to initialize `p` to point to `a`, you can use `int * p = &a` or `p = &a` instead, where `&` is the address-of operator. **NEVER** try to dereference uninitialized pointers! You will end up touching memory in an essentially arbitrary location, which could cause a segmentation fault (resulting in crash) or start overwriting other data in your program (resulting in obscure and non-reproducible bugs).

When you run your example code, `p` and `&a` have different values precisely because `p` was never assigned to point to the address of `a`. Some short background on why you might get any nonzero value in `p` at all: local variables are assigned from a special region of memory known as the *stack*, which also stores information about function calls and return addresses. Each process has their own stack. Crucially, though, unused regions of the stack aren't really zeroed out or otherwise cleaned up before use (except maybe in debug builds, which tend to assign really obvious values like `0xCCCCCCCC` or `0xBAADF00D` to uninitialized pointers). If your compiler doesn't automatically set default values for you (and release builds generally won't have such automatic initialization, for efficiency's sake), what you are seeing in `p` is what *happened* to be located in the memory assigned to `p` before your program set up its stack frame.

Comment: thanks for the info, but what I consider is `*p` represents the value at that address so it should accept any integer provided to it on the RHS. Apart from this could you explain why `&a` and `p` when outputted displays two different values?

Answer (score 2):

`int *p = a;` initializes a pointer `p` with `a` which isn't a pointer (hence the error), while `*p=a;` assigns `a` to the memory pointed to by `p`, syntactically speaking. Also, the former is an *initialization*, while the latter is *assignment*.

Note that in your case, `*p=a` invokes **undefined behavior**, as `p` doesn't point to program's legal memory, i.e you have not allocated memory for `p`.

Answer (score 1):

You store `a` at the address that `p` points to (`*p`). If you want to store the address of `a` (`&a`) in `p`, you must use

```
p = &a;
```

Using `int *p = a`, gives an error, because `p` is a `int*`, while `a` is an `int`. Think of it as `int* p = a`.

Answer (score 0):

`int *p = a;` - This means you are declaring a variable and assinging values to it. Variable name is `p` and its type is `int *` value you are assiging is `a` (10) which will be assigned to `p`. `int *p = a;` is equivalent to

```
int *p; 
p = a;
```

We cant assing a `int` value to `int *`.

`*p = a;` - This you are assing `int` to the `*p` not `p`. so this is fine. Before doing this dont forget to allocate memory for `p` other it may leads to crash(undefined behaviour) because `p` might have some garbage values.

I hope you are trying to assing address of `a` to `p`. In that you case you can do like below.

```
int a;
int *p = &a;
```